# PDF file randomly breaks upon upload

Tags: php, uploads, pdf

The issue randomly started happening. When I upload a PDF file via the media library, it sometimes 'adds' random lines and graphics to the PDF file(or solid brown color), but sometimes it is okay.
WP core is updated to latest, plugins as well, php is running 7.3.
I wonder if it is ever Wordpress issue or a hosting issue.

What could be the reason?

EDIT:
here's the list of the plugins:

```
Abandoned Cart Lite for WooCommerce
Advanced Custom Fields PRO
Advanced Order Export For WooCommerce
Contact Form 7
LionScripts: IP Blocker Lite
Mouseflow for Wordpress
MultiLine files for Contact Form 7
NotificationX
Post SMTP
Really Simple SSL
SVG Support
WooCommerce
WooCommerce Order Status Control
WooCommerce Order Status Manager
WooCommerce Stripe Gateway
WP Cerber Security, Anti-spam & Malware Scan
WP-PageNavi
Yoast SEO Premium
```

Which one has a chance to be the problem?

EDIT 2: here's what the PDF looks like(only one of the pages, other ones are fine actually:
[image]

Also, the XHR Request sometimes responds with JSON data, and sometimes the response is empty. This is all RANDOM, very weird bug.

EDIT 3: it's not from a plugin, I have disabled them all except the acf

**EDIT 4: I have found it is not inserting _wp_attachment_metadata in the wp_postmeta table(it works only through media library, but not from the acf file field)**

EDIT 5 : Just found out it breaks png and jpg images on upload too

EDIT 6 : It does the same thing on blank WP installation on BASIC media upload

Comment: WordPress does not modify PDF files on upload, but if your theme or plugins are doing this you would need to ask each plugin vendor individually if they modify PDF uploads or not, or disable them and re-test.

Comment: Check with other PDF may be PDF corrupted or graphics not proper set when PDF Create.

Comment: If you just want to show your PDF on the website, upload it to Scribd and embed it on the site.

Comment: Can you share the direct link to download the pdf, I need to see that pdf what affects the pdf.

Comment: are you using some kind of CDN that may tries to compress image files ?, or perhaps your hosting is compressing images

Comment: website is behind cloudflare, it shouldn't compress the files. Not sure about the hosting, it is shared plan on fastcomet